# OpenLiberty (WAS) support in Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

is there any way to configure OpenLiberty (17.0.0.X) in idea's *application servers*?
I use IDEA ultimate 2017.2 and tried straightforward approach:

Edit configurations -> Add new -> Websphere Local

When I point OL home directory IJ complaints that it's not valid.

I know WAS and OL are a "different species", just looking for any way to integrate local OL with idea.

[image]

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenLiberty support [was added](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-180631) in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 version.